# Force android alarm to trigger out of schedule

Tags: android, notifications, android-service, google-cloud-messaging

I have an alarm that is set with `AlarmManager`. I also have `GCM` (Google Cloud Messaging) broadcast receiver. Alarm is *rung* to call service to fetch new messages from server. `GCM` is used to get notifications of new *instant* messages and display a notification or download new *non-instant* messages.

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent("NAME");
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0 );
int type = AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP;
long interval = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR;
long triggerTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + interval;
am.setInexactRepeating(type, triggerTime, interval, pi);
```

Alarm triggers service that fetches all messages. `GCM` receives ONLY *instant* messages OR notification of *non-instant* messages.

I need to call the service to download messages if `GCM` arrives with *non-instant* messages notification. Problem is: I might get `GCM`, call a service from `GCM`, download messages, stop service. Next minute alarm triggers and service is started again. Since the service processes and stores messages, it puts a load on the device. I don't want the service to start more often than **once** per hour.

So I need to trigger the existing alarm and reset the clock, so that the next alarm is triggered at least 1 hour later. Is it possible to do without deleting the alarm from `GCM` service and then re-creating it?